# Is there a php based gantt chart tool that any one knows off?

Tags: php, mysql, gd

I am looking to try and implement a project management system for myself that is based on a LAMP implementation. The issue I have is that I would like to generate a gantt chart from the tasks/mile stones in the DB does anyone know of an open source gantt chart generator that will create images for a web based portal or better still a PHP/GD solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JpGraph](http://jpgraph.net) can generate Gantt charts, here's an example :

[image: JpGraph gantt chart]

There is also this [class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2737-PHP-Generate-project-progress-Gantt-charts.html)

Answer (score 1):

One I've used in the past is [Fusion Charts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/free/). I know it's flash based, but they are pretty customizable, and look much nicer than any of the alternatives I looked at. They also have a [pretty well documented PHP class](http://www.fusioncharts.com/free/docs/Contents/PHPClassAPI/Functions.html) that you can use to generate the graphs with ease.